# Getting ORA-01722: invalid number in Spring Data query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entity, jpa-2.0

I have two tables joined by non primary keys. This SQL query outputs 3 values as expected.

Its looking for the primary key of Department table. department2_.deptno
Therefore I will try  @EmbeddedId.

Comment: Your join column should be emp_dept_code, no?

Comment: @Angular_Newbie did you found something?

Comment: Yes.  The table didn't have a primary ID so I used ROWID as primary key and it worked.. duhh..lol.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table didn't have a primary ID so I used ROWID as primary key and it worked.. 
[JPA entity has no primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397393/jpa-entity-has-no-primary-key)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in the `Where` statement:

```
employee.emp_dept_code In(employee.department)
```

**Update**

you are trying to compare a number to varchar2 in where statement.

Comment: Exactly.  That is what In(employee.department) does.  I will override equals and hashcode then use @EmbeddedId as these 2 fields are composite.

Comment: You have to compare number to number or varchar2 to varchar2, or the DB engine will spam this error "ORA-01722: invalid number error", or other like that, your error is in your SQL statement not in spring data.

Comment: Yes.  This is in the query.  In(employee.department).  I believe this maps to id.   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
   mappedBy = "department")
 private Set<Employee> employeee = new HashSet<>();   Therefore I have to create embeddedid to compare.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on UNIX/ LINUX operating system, then the table names in MySQL are case sensitive.

So I always recommend to have lower case table name for `@Table(name = "<your_table>")` and create table with lowercase letters in create query. Idea is to be consistent if your company have guidelines.

You can also make MySQL case insensitive follow [this tutorial](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59407/how-to-make-mysql-table-name-case-insensitive-in-ubuntu#answer-69330)

Comment: Thanks however I'm sure the table names aren't a problem as I can run basic queries.  My issue is JPA Entity mapping.  One to Many Many to many.  I think I'm on the right path.  I'll let you know what happens.